# Apache error "Truncated or oversized response headers received from daemon process" when using Django

Tags: django, apache, mod-wsgi

We have a Django application using mod_wsgi working fine on our Ubuntu 16 instance. When we spun up a new Ubuntu 18 instance, and attempt to log into our application, we get:

```
[Tue Jan 10 22:12:00.930300 2023] [wsgi:error] [pid 11481:tid 140103479047936] [client 10.61.23.144:61958] Truncated or oversized response headers received from daemon process 'server': /home/.../wsgi.py, referer: https://application/login/?next=/application/
[Tue Jan 10 22:12:00.931998 2023] [core:notice] [pid 6523:tid 140103626501056] AH00052: child pid 11479 exit signal Segmentation fault (11)
```

In searching for answers, we've seen several posts suggesting that we add this line to our apache2.conf file, which we did:

```
WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
```

However, this did not address the problem. Also tried the suggestions noted on https://serverfault.com/questions/844761/wsgi-truncated-or-oversized-response-headers-received-from-daemon-process, but this also did not solve the problem.

We increased Apache logging to `info` but aside from the "Truncated or oversized response headers" and "Segmentation fault" no other information was logged.

Hoping we may have missed a trick or two.

Answer (score 0):

This solved the issue for us: https://github.com/psycopg/psycopg2/issues/543.

Specifically, installing psycopg2 library from source.